I want VBA to turn specific cells white/yellow and change font colour based on the right-most 7 and 8 letters of cell M3
I'm not certain where it goes wrong, but nothing really happens.
Sub Worksheet_ChangePartTwo(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("M3").Value = "Halvår " Then
    If Len(Range("M3").Value) = 7 Then
            Range("C42:E54").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' background
            Range("C42:E54").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' font
        End If
    ElseIf Range("M3").Value = "Kvartal " Then
        If Len(Range("M3").Value) = 8 Then
            Range("C42:C46,C50:C54,E42:E46,E50:E54").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow background
            Range("C42:C46,C50:C54,E42:E46,E50:E54").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'black font
        End If
    End If
End Sub

I've tried running the code and stepping into to debug, without much added info..



Why do you define a parameter for the Sub, when it is not used in it?  How do you invoke it? To get the right of a string use the Right function.

Why not just use Conditional Formatting and avoid VBA altogether?

@FrankBall I want the Text, Cells and edges to be removed all together, when they are irrelevant. I don't see how Conditional formatting achieves this? You are welcome to enlighten me, if i'm unaware of it's powers.

A Worksheet Change: Change Colors Based On Cell Value

Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1

The following code has to be copied to the correct sheet module (right-click the tab and select View Code).
It runs automatically each time a cell is changed i.e. you enter or clear a value or a formula, or you use VBA to do the same.
The signature Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) is unique for this event so if you change it, the code will not run as expected (at all).

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Worksheet_ChangePartOne Target
    Worksheet_ChangePartTwo Target
End Sub


Standard Module, e.g. Module1

For a specified range (rg), its sheet can be referenced with rg.Worksheet.
You cannot use the character å in the code. Either read it from a cell or use the ChrW function.

Option Explicit

Sub Worksheet_ChangePartOne(ByVal Target As Range)
' Change this to something more descriptive...

    ' Don't know what's going on here!

End Sub

Sub Worksheet_ChangePartTwo(ByVal Target As Range)
' Change this to something more descriptive, e.g. 'HighlightKvartal'.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    Dim tcell As Range: Set tcell = ws.Range("M3")
    If Intersect(tcell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim tString As String: tString = CStr(tcell.Value)
    
    If StrComp(tString, "Halv" & ChrW(229) & "r ", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        With ws.Range("C42:E54")
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' white background
            .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' white font
        End With
    
    ElseIf StrComp(tString, "Kvartal ", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' is equal
        With ws.Range("C42:C46,C50:C54,E42:E46,E50:E54")
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow background
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'black font
        End With
    
    'ElseIf   Then
    
    'ElseIf   Then
    
    'ElseIf   Then
    
    'ElseIf   Then
    
    Else ' what to do if e.g. blank?
        
    End If

End Sub


Appreciate the answer. I  have some follow up if you wouldn't mind :)
The M3 cell has a spare after the last letter in kvartal and Halvår - vill i just need to add that in the end of "Kvartal " and "r " like so?
Code is copied to the right sheet.
Can you try to explain this: "The signature Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) is unique for this event so if you change it, the code will not run as expected." a bit further?
So if i have another sub by that name, i'm better off including this code in the sub, than having two?

I'm out of time. I'll answer in the afternoon if it's reasonable. Sorry.

No worries, i'll gladly wait, no rush :) Appreciate the time taken anyway. Learning the language bit by bit.

I'm still having issues.. Nothing happens when i enter your most recent edit..?
Regards to do "if e.g. blank?", it won't happen. It's a drop down menu with 6 options (Picture of the drop down has been added to the post)

The info you are providing is not accurate. Decide if you'll have 6 cases or 2. The latest edit assumes the former. It is understood that you'll have to replace e.g. Halv with e.g. 1. Halv. If you want to stick with 2 cases, use the out-commented lines that say "contains" (>0) in my initial post instead.

It has always been 6 cases. Sorry if that has been unclear. At first i tried to have the code look at the last x-amount of letters , so it didn't care about the numbers.
I've tried copypaste the latest edit and it doesn't work for me when i use the drop down. I've also just in case, tried to make all 6 cases each their own (with 1. , 2. etc prior to Halv or Kvartal.), knowing it might be overkill.. Still didn't work though.. Any ideas as to why nothing seems to work...?

"knowing it might be overkill" tells me there are 2 relevant cases (color sets) so the solution is "contains" i.e. If InStr(1, tString, "Halv" & ChrW(229) & "r", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then and ElseIf InStr(1, tString, "Kvartal", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then. Check if Kvartalis spelled correctly. Check if the dropdown is still in cell M3. Check if the Private Sub ... is in the correct sheet module. Note that if M3 contains a formula retrieving the value from the dropdown cell, it won't work.

not sure why you want to check the length of the string after you have checked the string equals to Halvår or Kvartal . You can just trim it with function TRIM before performing comparison. eg: TRIM(string). The code below works in my environment.
You should not change your sub name to PartTwo as it is VBA build-in event name. changing it would cause VBA don't regnonize it.
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Trim(Range("M3").Value) = "Halvår" Then
        
            Range("C42:E54").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' background
            Range("C42:E54").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' font
       
    ElseIf Trim(Range("M3").Value) = "Kvartal" Then
       
            Range("C42:C46,C50:C54,E42:E46,E50:E54").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow background
            Range("C42:C46,C50:C54,E42:E46,E50:E54").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'black font
    End If

End Sub


Appreciate it.
If my 6 options are "1. Halvår ", "2. Halvår ", 1. Kvartal " etc. with 2-4th kvartal. (And yes, there are spaces on the end on purpose.) Will the Trim function work and if so, how does it work? Is it a drop-down, if that changes anything.
Still new to the game, so didn't know about the sub name thing. When can one pick and choose their own sub name, and when is it set in stone?
